# Empty DataFrame created with column names from another existing DataFrame. Need to filter rows based on colmun value match

Tags: python-3.x

When i am trying to create another dataframe using existing dataframe created from excel sheet using pandas, the new dataframe is created as empty dataframe with only column names.

Code:

```
import pandas
import tkinter
from tkinter import *

xls_data = pandas.ExcelFile("data/Test.xlsx")

current_item = listbox.get(listbox.curselection())

# read xls file 
items_sheet = pandas.read_excel(xls_data, sheet_name="Items")
# prints the 304 rows with 40 columns
print(items_sheet)  

items_df = items_sheet.loc[(items_sheet["Skill 1"] == current_item), ['Name', 'Category', 'Rarity', 'Type', 'Slot','Level', 'Skill 1', 'Skill 2', 'skill 3', 'skill 4', 'class skill', 'class skill2','class skill3']]

print(items_df)
```

Output:

```
               Name Category     Rarity  ... Resistance 3 Unnamed: 40  blueprint
0     Ascendant Cowl       MI       rare  ...          NaN         NaN        NaN
1     Ascendant Hood       MI       rare  ...          NaN         NaN        NaN
2    Ascended Casque       MI       rare  ...          NaN         NaN        NaN
3    Ascended Diadem       MI       rare  ...          NaN         NaN        NaN
4        Chosen Gaze       MI       rare  ...          NaN         NaN        NaN
..               ...      ...        ...  ...          ...         ...        ...
299              NaN  faction  legendary  ...          NaN         NaN        NaN
300              NaN  faction  legendary  ...          NaN         NaN        NaN
301              NaN  faction  legendary  ...          NaN         NaN        NaN
302              NaN  faction  legendary  ...          NaN         NaN        NaN
303              NaN  faction  legendary  ...          NaN         NaN        NaN

[304 rows x 42 columns]
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Name, Category, Rarity, Type, Slot, Level, Skill_1, Skill_2, Skill_3, Skill_4, class_skill1, class_skill2, class_skill3]
Index: []
```

I m trying to extract only the rows which has column
**"Skill 1" == current_item **
and fetch that row in the DF to print.